# Autowired field does not get set based on order of declaration

Tags: java, spring-boot

It seems like @Autowired field has some effect on order of declaration. Here is the code snippets which works

```
@Autowired
private ApmProperties apmProperties;

@Autowired
private ApmUaaRestClient apmUaaRestClient;

public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(AlertTemplateApplication.class, args);
}
```

However if I change the order of declaration, I get both them set to null. Can anyone please point out the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Does `ApmUaaRestClient` use `ApmProperties `?

Comment: @HerrDerb - Yes - It does